# Polygons one beside another

Tags: tkz-euclide, tkz-collection, polygon

I'm trying to do two regular polygons side by side, but the second one always gets bigger then what I want. Could anyone help me?

This requires `tkz-obj-polygons.tex`, which a beta-version of code for making regular polygons (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35291/), that can be downloaded from http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/euclide/tkz-obj-polygons.tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{-4/0/A, -1/0/B, 5/0/C, 7.5/0/D}

    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-5,-1.5) grid (10,5.5);
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (-5,0) -- (10,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw [->, >=stealth] (0,-1.5) -- (0,5) node [above] {$y$};

    \tkzDefRegPolygon[side,sides=5](A,B)\tkzGetPoint{O}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5)

    \tkzDefRegPolygon[side,sides=6](C,D)\tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6)

    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,C,D)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the second draw OK if you comment out the first? It seems odd that it's picking up all the points except D correctly.

Comment: If I comment out the first, the second looks like in this image yet.

Comment: I doubt it will fix anything but your first shape refers to points based on `O` but then draws to points based on `P`; the second just uses `P`.

Comment: I just can't fix it. I've tryed everything, I tryed to build the hexagon separeted but still don't work.

Comment: Some very odd behavior. Looks like a bug. Since it's @Alain Matthes package, he will want to know.

Comment: The question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35266/hexagon-with-exscribed-triangle?rq=1) gives the download link [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/euclide/tkz-obj-polygons.tex). I downloaded the file tkz-obj-polygons.tex and can confirm there are a lot of strange problems when I experimented with the code. Now, however, I'm unable to connect to his site (browser times out because site takes too long to respond.

Comment: @Irlexi  Bug in my code, B instead of #1 in `\tkzCalcLength[cm](tkz@tempPt,#1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting for the next version here is a correction

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetkzobj{all}
\makeatletter
\def\tkzRegPolygonSide(#1,#2){
\begingroup  
% get the center 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tkz@regangle}{360/\tkz@regpolsides*(\tkz@regpolsides-1)} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tkz@regangleside}{(180-\tkz@regangle)/2} 
\tkzDefMidPoint(#1,#2)\tkzGetPoint{tkz@tempPt} 
\tkzCalcLength\[cm\](tkz@tempPt,#1) \tkzGetLength{tkz@len} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tkz@inscriberadius}{%
     \tkz@len*tan(90*(\tkz@regpolsides-2)/\tkz@regpolsides)} 
\tkzDefPointWith\[orthogonal normed,K=\tkz@inscriberadius\](tkz@tempPt,#2)   
\tkzGetPoint{tkz@RegPolCenter} 
\tkzRegPolygonCenter(tkz@RegPolCenter,#1)       
\tkzRenamePoint(tkz@RegPolCenter){tkzPointResult}  
\endgroup
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\[scale=1\]
    \tkzDefPoints{-4/0/A, -1/0/B, 5/0/C, 7/0/D}

    \draw\[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed\] (-5,-1.5) grid (10,5.5);
    \draw \[->, >=stealth\] (-5,0) -- (10,0) node \[right\] {$x$};
    \draw \[->, >=stealth\] (0,-1.5) -- (0,5) node \[above\] {$y$};


    \tkzDefRegPolygon\[side,sides=5,name=P\](A,B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon\[thick\](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5)

    \tkzDefRegPolygon\[side,sides=6,name=R\](C,D)
    \tkzDrawPolygon\[thick\](R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6)

    \tkzLabelPoints\[below\](A,B,C,D)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I end up with somithing else by that time, but is still useful.