# What methods can I use to construct a circle in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm trying to learn to do geometric constructions in LaTeX, in particular construct a cyclic convex hexagon, but I'm struggling to find any documentation for tkz-euclide that is useful in an introductory way. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Why the reference to French? The [documentation of tkz-euclide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf) is in English. I understand the question as asking for a tutorial.

Comment: Do you want to *construct* a hexagon geometrically, or do you want to *draw* a hexagon? For the latter, see e.g. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345978](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345978/110998)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35266/hexagon-with-exscribed-triangle